# Implement plugin install/uninstall feature through Laravel packages

Tags: laravel, plugins, package, laravel-5.3

I am using Laravel 5.3. I am trying to develop a site where users can select plugins from a list and choose to install/uninstall and enable/disable them. For example, user can choose to install a Weather Widget(plugin) and then enable it in order to have it shown on their Dashboard.

I have been looking into 'packages' in Laravel, and so I have the idea to implement my plugins as packages. But my confusion is, once I have these packages in my Laravel project, how can I let users of my site install/enable them as plugins by simply selecting them from the list displayed to them?

Comment: Using Laravel packages as widgets for your users isn't going to work. Packages need to be added to the providers array etc as a global package for everyone otherwise it won't work. Unless I'm misunderstanding your plan, install packages properly, and then use a database and hasMany relationships to set whether a package is active for a user or not

Comment: @AndyHolmes that's where my confusion also lies. I can easily make all packages available for the users, and the users can choose to enable/disable them (and also keep record in db table as you said). But problem is I also need them to choose whether to install them, and also uninstall them later if they want; just like how we install/uninstall and enable/disable plugins/add-ons in our browsers, or in any CMS (ie Wordpress)

Comment: But it's not feasible to remove a package that other people depend on. Packages run on the laravel application, *not* the user profile

Comment: so having a true/false in a database is the only feasible option I can see here

Comment: @BangularTK As you talk about the plugin enable disable in cms/browser its is done by the adminstrator.

Comment: I think this echos what has been said mostly but if it helps: Technically you could write some shell script or something to automate installing and removing packages if you really found that necessary, but they would be removed for everyone using the application. If you are looking to build a CMS type thing and you actually want an admin to be able to install or remove packages for the app through the UI then you could implement something like this (or look for existing cms's). But if this is to be per user, all packages must be installed on the server with users optionally using them or not

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that I cannot do this by using Laravel packages or through any other framework, or even any CMS- since only the admin can handle packages/plugins for all the users. So, if I want to create something that gives the power to users to install plugins and enable them in their site dashboard, what do I need to do or use?